# Laravel Eloquent ORM Querying relationship inside relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Well, I am still working with Eloquent ORM and can't think of a "quick" solution for this: Now I think I need to recreate the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM properties
LEFT JOIN property_environments ON property_environments.property_id = properties.id
LEFT JOIN environments ON property_environments.environment_id = environments.id
WHERE environments.name = "Rooms"
AND property_environments.value = 2
```

I should say that all the tables have the required foreign keys where:

- **properties** - `App\Property`
- **property_environments** - `App\PropertyEnvironment`
- **environments** - `App\Environments`

[image: tables]

So, I want to select all the properties that have environments where its name is "Rooms" and its value is 2.

So I appreciate any comments on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't done so already, create the many-to-many relationship. Then you could do something along the lines of

```
Property::whereHas('environment', function($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'Rooms')
              ->where('value', 2);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: There is no need to use `withPivot` to make this work, but still, it's a good answer. +1

Comment: So, `Property` should have a many-to-many relationship with `PropertyEnvironment` or `Environment`?

Comment: `Property` should have a many-to-many relationship with `Environment`